# C# get first byte index from a byte array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a byte Array that contains the char '%' (25 hex, 37 decimal). I would like to get the index of this byte, however, none of these methods work, and -1 is returned. How to get the index of a specific byte in a byte array?

```
int byteIndex = Array.IndexOf(bytesDataArray, '%');
int byteIndex = Array.IndexOf(bytesDataArray, 37);
int byteIndex = Array.IndexOf(bytesDataArray, 0x25);
```

Comment: Bytes and chars are different types. What is _actually_ in the byte array?

Comment: `Array.IndexOf` has [overloads which take `object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-5.0#System_Array_IndexOf_System_Array_System_Object_), and so you need to make sure that the data type of the thing you're searching for is correct. You've got an array of *bytes*, but you're passing a *char*, and then two *ints*. If you make sure that you always pass a *byte*, [everything works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AUmk9C)

Comment: "I have a byte Array that contains the char" - A byte array contains bytes, not chars. You should separate those two concepts in your mind. I suspect that if you search for a *byte* instead of an int or a char, it will work...

Comment: @canton7: There *are* overloads of Array.IndexOf that are generic, but if those fail, it'll fall back on the non-generic one, which I believe is what's happening here.

Comment: @JonSkeet Spotted and corrected mere seconds before your comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to find an int value of 37 in a byte array. Byte arrays don't contain ints. You need to do a type cast:

```
int byteIndex = Array.IndexOf(bytesDataArray, (byte)37);
```

Comment: oh sure, casting was the solution. Thanks :)